# Software Installation

Tags: installation, server, skype, lamp

I want to install software on my Ubuntu 13.04 machine given below:-

- LAMP Server
- Skype

  From where I download and  install these software by using terminal

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not install WAMP on Linux. The W stands for Windows so on Linux you install LAMP.
Installation can be done by these 2 commands:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel
```

and choosing "install LAMP server":

[image]

This will install a pre configured webserver setup of apache, mysql, php that will let you get to the point where you can see a webpage showing "it works" out of the box (only thing you need to supply is a mysql user and password during installation).

(do not uncheck any of the checked options ;) )

Skype is in the partner repositories, wich can easily be enabled in the Software Center or running in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

[image]

Command line:

```
 sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: For skype you need fist enable the Third party repositories